# Is java.util automatically called in eclipse when you write your code ? where does it "get" the classes it imports?

Tags: java, eclipse, java.util.scanner

This code doesn't work:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputTest {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    { 
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.In);
        System.out.print("What is your name ?");
        String name = in.nextLine();

        System.out.print("How old are you?");
        int age = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Hello " + name + "You'll be");
    }
}
```

Does it have to do with my java.util at the beginning not working correctly ?
Error message: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    In cannot be resolved or is not a field

```
at InputTest.main(InputTest.java:6)
```

Comment: In `new Scanner(System.In)` you used a capital `I` instead of a lowercase `i`; it should be `new Scanner(System.in);`.  That's all.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with imports. The reference to the standard input in java is `System.in`, with a lowercase `i`, not a capital one:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
// Here ------------------------^
```